# How Can I resize image widget relatively?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want my image resize relatively from parent `Containerwidget` and defined `scale: 0.8,//here` in `AssetImage()` but it doesn't work ? How Can I fix this ?

```
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Wrap(
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print("test");
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                // color: Colors.green,
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  image: 
                                  DecorationImage(
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                    image: AssetImage('images/prop/lock.png'),
                                    scale: 0.8,//here
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

---

Additional comment
I think `LayoutBuilder()` doesn't work appropriately.
[image]

```
                      Container(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Wrap(
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                print("test");
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: 50,
                                height: 50,
                                // color: Colors.green,
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                ),
                                child: LayoutBuilder(
                                  builder: (context, constraints) {
                                    return Image.asset(
                                      'images/prop/lock.png',
                                      fit: BoxFit.none,
                                      height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.1,
                                      width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.1,
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: can you explain more? I didn't understand what you want?

Comment: Please see my screenshot above and even if change tha scale paramater, the image (actually lock icon) size ,  never changes like scale: from 0.5 to 1.0, no changes detected

Comment: It also means that I just want the lock image smaller than screenshot above and the size depends on the parenet widget, as the size of parent widget is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LayoutBuilder` like this:

```
Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Wrap(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                print("test");
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                alignment: Alignment.center,// important part
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  
                ),
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, constraints) {
                    return Image.asset(
                      'images/prop/lock.png',
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.3,
                      width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.3,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Appolgize for late reply. Im sorry, but it doesnt work, Could you please advise what's the reason ? Please refer to the additional comment above.

Comment: you forgot to use alignment: Alignment.center, for Container with 50 height.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use AspectRatio Class for that use, like this

```
final double size = MediaQuery.of(context).size.aspectRatio;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must change `fit` type to `BoxFit.none`, like this:

```
Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              print("test");
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              // color: Colors.green,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.none,    // change this line
                  image: AssetImage('images/prop/lock.png'),
                  scale: 0.8,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Comment: It also worked ! and apologize for my late reply.

Comment: By the way, the Image became smaller when I set bigger scale:value.  Actually, scale:10 would fit my layout ,  but wonder if this is correct behaviour or not ?